# Embedded link displays when hardcoded but not when passed as variable

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have the following problem in my django project when trying to display an embedded google maps link in my page. This works (renders the Google Maps iframe with a populated map) when I hardcode the src URL but not when I pass it in my context even though they result to the same text string.

This is my html `detailview.html`:

```
        {% if maps_link is not None %}
          <iframe
            src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=-28.4457436,21.268374&hl=en&z=14&amp;output=embed"            
            loading="lazy"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
          ></iframe>
        {% endif %}
```

The src URL as it is shown above displays as I want it to, but when I do the following:

```
        {% if maps_link is not None %}
          <iframe
            src="{{ maps_link }}"    <!-- This gets blocked -->   
            loading="lazy"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
          ></iframe>
        {% endif %}
```

then my browser gives me the following warning:

> To protect your security, [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it. To see this page, you need to open it in a new window.

This is my `views.py` where the context is generated. I tried to get around it by applying xframes exemptions but that made no difference:

```
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse

@xframe_options_exempt
def detail(request, database_reference):
    try:
        obj = Consolidated.objects.get(database_reference=database_reference)
    except Consolidated.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("This database object does not exist: " + database_reference)

    context = {
        "content" : content_list,
        "maps_link": obj.location_link
    }

    print(context['maps_link'])
    print(type(context['maps_link']))

    template = loader.get_template("home/detailview.html")
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

`print(context['maps_link'])` results to `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=-25.797944,28.307176&hl=en&z=14&amp;output=embed`

and

`print(type(context['maps_link']))` results in the following type `<class 'str'>`

So printing out the {{ maps_link }} value results to the exact same string as the hardcoded URL.
Can someone tell me why this is happening (what's the difference between a string hardcoded in the html side and a string passed as a parameter) and more importantly how I can get around it? Thanks

Comment: I see the coordinates are different in the hardcoded example than in the str received from the django model. You can assume that the behaviour is the same regardless of the exact coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, `&amp;` is automatically converted to the character `&`. Therefore, the URL

`https://maps.google.com/maps?q=-28.4457436,21.268374&hl=en&z=14&amp;output=embed`

is actually

`https://maps.google.com/maps?q=-28.4457436,21.268374&hl=en&z=14&output=embed`.

However, when Django does the substitution, it does NOT replace the special sequence `&amp;`. Therefore, the URL visited is a different one.

To resolve the issue, you can do the replacement yourself. Replace

```py
context = {
    "content" : content_list,
    "maps_link": obj.location_link
}
```

with

```py
context = {
    "content" : content_list,
    "maps_link": obj.location_link.replace('&amp;', '&')
}
```

and this should solve the issue.

Comment: Another way to solve the issue is to try and figure out how the `&amp;` got into your data in the first place and remove it from there.